# Loop an array of asynchronous functions without Promise.all() method

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise

There is an array with objects [{ some configurations }, { some configurations } ... ]; , for each element of array i want to call an asynchronous function that runs every 1 second (ideally with a setTimoute or setInterval ) independently from the others running functions.
So if an error occurs in one of the asynchronous functions, then the rest are not terminated, but keep running every second .The Promise.all() method does help me to solve above problem, so can you suggest me some way to solve it?

```
const array = [ { some configurations }, { some configurations}];
const intervalIds = array.map(() => null);

async function startAsyncFunction(index, params){
  connectMethod(params, async (err) => {
    if(error){
      // retry connect and run every second
      clearInterval(intervalIds[index]);
      intervalIds[i] = setInterval(() => {
        await startAsyncFunction(index, params)
      }, 1000);
    }
    // do some other stuff
  })
} 

async function startLooping(){
  for(let i = 0; i<= array.length -1; i++){
    const params = array[i] || {};
    intervalIds[i] = setInterval(() => {
      await startAsyncFunction(i, params)
    }, 1000);
  }
}

startLooping();
```

Comment: [`Promise.allSettled()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)?

Comment: And the problem/question is? And what have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: Use Promise.allSettled. Show more of your code.

Comment: *"call an asynchronous function that runs every 1 second"* That doesn't like something promises would help you with. Or do you mean that every second you are executing an async function for all objects? (though that seems weird too) The order of things matters here.

Comment: @Andreas  i edit my question to include relevant code

Comment: @TusharShahi  i edit my question to include relevant code

Comment: @FelixKling i edit my question to include relevant code

Comment: `setInterval(() => { await startAsyncFunction(i, params) }, 1000)` - `setInterval()` doesn't care about the `await` keyword.